# How can I get this type view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

[image]

I want to make this type of card view but only get an aligned column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you will need the StaggeredGridLayoutManager https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager